# Custom devise authenticate method in user model rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

Is there a way I could create a custom authenticate method which accepts username,password and some other custom attribute?

So I could do User.authenticate('user123', 'secret123', 'attr1')

Comment: were you able to use the method User.authenticate(email, password). Actually when I called a it I got an error - undefined method `authenticate'. Does deveise provide a method like this?  Can share how you created a custom method authenticate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb:
config.authentication_keys = [ :username, :attr1 ]
```

That should be it :)

You can read more on the [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address).